# How to execute Gdata client application in iphone os 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, gdata-api, gdata

I have downloaded the Gdata objective c client application from [GoogleCode](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/detail?name=gdata-objectivec-client-1.11.0.zip) but when I opened any application all are for MAC and not for iPhone.

Can any one suggest me how to use the gData application for iPhone os 4.2.1.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of the library is the same for iOS and for Mac. Just add the library to your project as described on the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary) and follow the [directions](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction) on using the library.

Comment: thanks for this reply. But one thing the code provided by google it self in the download option is working with MAC applications can we make the same for iPhone app ? Is it possible ?

Comment: The library is plain Cocoa and Objective-C. It does not have anything to do with the user interface, so it works the same for iOS and for Mac applications.  The sample applications are designed to show how to use the library for API calls; it does not teach iOS or Mac user interface coding.